# jQuery - hide/show buttons on a dialog dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-dialog

I have a dialog -

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="msg-popup">
  <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Notification</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content" id> 
    <b id="notif-subject"></b>  
    <a href="#notif-details1" id:"show-notif" data-role="button">Show notification</a>
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button">Cancel</a>
  </div> 
</div>
```

I want to hide and show the show-notif button dynamically using jquery code. How would I do it?

I have tried

```
$("#show-notif").hide();
```

This did not work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Attribute should be set with equal `=` sign: `<a id="show-notif"> ... </a>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is small syntax error:

```
<a href="#notif-details1" id:"show-notif" data-role="button">Show notification</a>
```

it should be (replaced `:` with `=`):

```
<a href="#notif-details1" id="show-notif" data-role="button">Show notification</a>
```

Those functions should work:

```
$('#show-notif').hide();
$('#show-notif').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

this line in your HTML code replace with

```
<a href="#notif-details1" id:"show-notif" data-role="button">Show notification</a>
```

this

```
<a href="#notif-details1" id="show-notif" data-role="button">Show notification</a>
```

because you need to use

```
id="show-notif"
```

jsfiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/MfQeF/

Answer (score 0):

id:"show-notif" is not a valid statement.

it should be id="show-notif"

Use Firefox (or Chrome) with plugins such as html validator - or web developer . It can show your syntax errors.